# Sigar API Java ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, classnotfoundexception, sigar

I have downloaded Sigar API from their website and included `sigar.jar` file into my project in Eclipse.

But the problem is I need `.java` files inorder to convert my project into obj-c.

So I dowloaded zip file from the github and copied src folder from `sigar-master/bindings/java/src/org/hyperic/sigar` but some classes are not found in them.

Given example code is running fine when jar is included but when .java files are included the code is not running.

Where I am going wrong?

Thank you!

---

Code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.lang.*;


import org.hyperic.sigar.Mem; // Eclipse says that The import org.hyperic.sigar.Mem cannot be resolved
import org.hyperic.sigar.Sigar;
import org.hyperic.sigar.SigarException;

public class MemExample {

private static Sigar sigar = new Sigar();

public static void getInformationsAboutMemory() {
    System.out.println("**************************************");
    System.out.println("*** Informations about the Memory: ***");
    System.out.println("**************************************\n");

    Mem mem = null;  // Mem cannot be resolved to a type
    try {
        mem = sigar.getMem();  // The method getMem() from the type Sigar refers to the missing type Mem
    } catch (SigarException se) {
        se.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("Actual total free system memory: "
            + mem.getActualFree() / 1024 / 1024+ " MB");
    System.out.println("Actual total used system memory: "
            + mem.getActualUsed() / 1024 / 1024 + " MB");
    System.out.println("Total free system memory ......: " + mem.getFree()
            / 1024 / 1024+ " MB");
    System.out.println("System Random Access Memory....: " + mem.getRam()
            + " MB");
    System.out.println("Total system memory............: " + mem.getTotal()
            / 1024 / 1024+ " MB");
    System.out.println("Total used system memory.......: " + mem.getUsed()
            / 1024 / 1024+ " MB");

    System.out.println("\n**************************************\n");


}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{ // line 45

            getInformationsAboutMemory();

            }

}
```

Console:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 

at MemExample.main(MemExample.java:45)
```

It says that `Mem cannot be resolved to a type`

When I unzipped `sigar.jar` there is a class `Mem.class` in it.

Comment: Show the complete stacktrace

Comment: @Jens Pls check the edit.